Getting "ValueError Encountered text corresponding to disallowed special token '<|endoftext|>'" while running CrewAI
I am running CrewAI with the Ollama Phi3 model, which runs well as long as I am not asked to generate sample Python code. Things get complicated when the Developer Agent passes a response to the HumanProxy Agent. Crew never finishes the work and continuously produces the following output:

2024-05-02 14:24:07,361 - 129651365437888 - manager.py-manager:281 - WARNING: Error in TokenCalcHandler.on_llm_start callback: ValueError("Encountered text corresponding to disallowed special token '<|endoftext|>'.\nIf you want this text to be encoded as a special token, pass it to allowed_special, e.g. allowed_special={'<|endoftext|>', ...}.\nIf you want this text to be encoded as normal text, disable the check for this token by passing disallowed_special=(enc.special_tokens_set - {'<|endoftext|>'}).\nTo disable this check for all special tokens, pass disallowed_special=().\n")

Output from running the Crew:
>>> result = crew.kickoff()
 [DEBUG]: == Working Agent: Senior Manager
 [INFO]: == Starting Task: Create python script that scrape the websites and saves the output into the text file fo further processing.
  Manage the work with your crew to answer the request. 
  Check with Human if the response was helpful and if it is not satisfactory then try again. 


> Entering new CrewAgentExecutor chain...
Thought: I need to delegate tasks efficiently among my crew members to create a Python script for web scraping that saves output into a text file.
Action: Delegate work to co-worker
Action Input: {"coworker": "Python Developer", "task": "Create a Python script for web scraping and saving the output into a text file.", "context": "The task involves using libraries like BeautifulS Authorization (BeautifulSoup) or Scrapy to scrape websites. The data extracted should be saved in a structured format, such as JSON or CSV, which can then be processed further."}

> Entering new CrewAgentExecutor chain...
Thought: To complete this task effectively, I need to select a suitable library for web scraping, define the target website URL, specify the data elements to be extracted, and then write Python code that will scrape the desired information and save it in JSON format.

Final Answer:
```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Define the URL of the website you want to scrape
url = 'https://example.com'  # Replace with actual target website URL

def web_scrape(target_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(target_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Assuming we want to extract data from elements with a specific class or id
        data_elements = []  # Replace this with the actual logic for selecting data elements
        for element in soup.select('your-selector'):  # Replace 'your-selector' with appropriate CSS selector(s)
            extracted_data = {
                'element_id': element['id'],  # Assuming each element has an id attribute
                'text': element.get_text()
            }
            data_elements.append(extracted_data)
        
        # Save the scraped data into a JSON file
        with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(data_elements, json_file, indent=4)
            
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while making the request: {e}")

# Execute the web scraping function
web_scrape(url)
```
Replace `'https://example.com'` with your actual target website URL and adjust the data extraction logic according to the specific elements you need to scrape from that site.<|end|><|endoftext|>

> Finished chain.
 

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Define the URL of the website you want to scrape
url = 'https://example.com'  # Replace with actual target website URL

def web_scrape(target_url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(target_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Assuming we want to extract data from elements with a specific class or id
        data_elements = []  # Replace this with the actual logic for selecting data elements
        for element in soup.select('your-selector'):  # Replace 'your-selector' with appropriate CSS selector(s)
            extracted_data = {
                'element_id': element['id'],  # Assuming each element has an id attribute
                'text': element.get_text()
            }
            data_elements.append(extracted_data)
        
        # Save the scraped data into a JSON file
        with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:
            json.dump(data_elements, json_file, indent=4)
            
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while making the request: {e}")

# Execute the web scraping function
web_scrape(url)
```
Replace `'https://example.com'` with your actual target website URL and adjust the data extraction logic according to the specific elements you need to scrape from that site.<|end|><|endoftext|>


Well <|endoftext|> is the default stop token in many llm models.
I think you are using <|endoftext|> somewhere in your prompts.
Either:

remove stop token from your prompt
or, use allowed_special={'<|endoftext|>'} in your api call.

